# How do I check for an object at a certain position?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have a black targetBox that is used to check the area it covers for the existence of Block objects such as the grey one in the top left hand corner and return a boolean if there is a Block at that position.
It's a tile system and I have included one case where it would return "false" and one that would return "true".

[image: This would return false]

[image: This would return true]

I understand I can do something like

```
public bool checkTargetObjects()
{
    if(block.x == target.x && block.y == target.y) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

But I am unsure of how to look for Block objects at the position. How can I do this?

Comment: So you can check if an object exists at a certain location, are you just asking how to check if a "Block" is *also* at that location?

Comment: Nope, I am not there yet. I am asking how to check if there is something at that location x,y. The block is more for context

Comment: Instead of going with X and Y positions for your tiles, use the Rectangle object. Then you'll be able to do rect1.Intersect(rect2)

Comment: I am using the Rectangle object and what you suggested actually looks very usable! Like targetBox.Intersect(blockBox) but the problem I am having is that I am checking for any block not just a specific one. Like targetBox.Intersect(any blockBox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the X and Y position of your tiles, save that data as a [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx). The only additional thing you need is the Width and Height of your tiles (which should be a constant somewhere).

So instead of having

```
public class Block 
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

you can have

```
public class Block 
{
    public Rectangle Area { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can take all your blocks (Let's say you got them all in a `List<Block>` called `blocks`) and iterate over them to see which one intersects with your Target :

```
var blocksInTarget = blocks.Where(b => b.Area.Intersects(target.Area));
```

where `Area` is your rectangle.

If you only want to know if there is a rectangle (and not which ones), you can change that `Where` with `Any`, which you can read as "Return true if there is any block intersecting my target" :

```
bool isBlockPresent = blocks.Any(b => b.Area.Intersects(target.Area));
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me figure it out. I defined Intersects and I think we're gonna be okay :D

Comment: @PepperTheDog _"I defined Intersects"_ - There is no need to write an implementation for **Intersects**.  Just use the one provided by XNA in `Rectangle` as mentioned by Pierre-Luc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a compare double function like

```
  const THRESH = 1e-3; // define as desired for your application
   public bool compareDoubles(double a1, double a2)
   {
      if( fabs(a1-a2) < THRESH)
          return true;
     else
          return false;
   }
```

This allows for a tolerance from getting ONLY exact matches, which are rare for dobules!
Then you would use the function on the x and y dimensions of each object (and z if anyone is using 3D).  you could even make THRESH a parameter if there is a significant difference in the tolerance on a per dimension basis.